# XCode clang error when building project Prefix.pch.dia not found

Tags: xcode, macos, clang

I am getting that error when compiling project in XCode on Mac OSX Mountain Lion

`clang: error: no such file or directory:       '/Users/bartg/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/storeq-osx-gifnhelgkswbtpdzwjxydyudncxu/Build/Intermediates/PrecompiledHeaders/storeq-osx-Prefix-dskqrphwleosxlcoaimwmmhoneea/storeq-osx-Prefix.pch.dia'`

I spent a lot of time searching the web and found no solution. Anybody knows why this is happening?

Comment: Same issue with several devs in the office here.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using CocoaPods 0.18.0, this might be cause by CocoaPods and is fixed in https://github.com/CocoaPods/CocoaPods/issues/956

Comment: Unfortunately I am not using CocoaPods :(